# Excel equivalent of T-SQL EXISTS

Tags: excel, exists

In T-SQL one can very easily find rows matching a criteria with the EXISTS clause of a statement.

Say you have a table containing rows with start- and end dates one can very easily find the rows where some date is between the start- and end dates of the rows in this table.

```
Select * from sometable s where exists (select * from anothertable a where s.somedate between a.startdate and a.enddate)
```

I need this functionality or a workaround for this in Excel. I need to show calculations in the Excel-file so I do not see it as an option to move the data to SQL and use T-SQL for this and then just paste the results back in Excel.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You can use ADO to query an Excel spreadsheet.

in VBA create ADODB Connection

```
objConn.Open "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" & _
"Data Source=C:\Test.xls; Extended Properties=""Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes;"";"
```

and run a query:

```
objRecordset.Open "Select * FROM [Sheet1$] WHERE [F1] IN (SELECT [F2] FROM [Sheet1$])", objConn
```

Note: Untested code, idea from memory.